# How to convert PNG to uncompressed DDS in Linux?

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, dds-format

Based on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface) DDS could be compressed and uncompressed.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to achive converting `png` to `dds` without compression.

Regular converting could be achived with
`convert file.png out.dds`

Comment: Untested, but try putting `-compress none` before the output filename.

Comment: Check if the result is compressed with `identify -verbose out.dds`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `Compression: DXT5` in `identify` info. I've tried to put `-compress none` in different positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you found a missing feature in ImageMagick. This is now only supported:

`convert file.png -define dds:compression=none out.dds`

But the following should work:

`convert file.png -compress none out.dds`

I just pushed a patch to the ImageMagick repository to add support for the `-compress` option that will be available in the next release.

Comment: Trying to convert dds to png on Linux. But getting this error: "convert: improper image header". {I don't have ImageMagick}